# is there corresponding class in C++ as TreeMap in Java?

Tags: java, c++

is  there corresponding class in  C++  as TreeMap in Java?
thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, `std::map`, found in the `<map>` Standard Library header.

Answer (score 8):

I think an STL map might be what you want.

Its implementation might be different; I believe it's based on a red-black tree.

Comment: *Its implementation might be different; I believe it's based on a red-black tree.* so is java's treemap

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be based on a red-black tree; it just has to have the same performance characteristics.